# My HDD is mounted as read only

Tags: 18.04, mount, windows-10

I have installed ubuntu over `windows10` and then I have mounted another HDD. It was mounted successfully but when try to open it is `read only`. I can't access it for writing. I have tried all solutions for `ntfs` partition.

When check partition it is showing like this as on type `microsoft basic data`.

I have completely removed `windows10`.

Comment: External mounts are always mounted by root. Please check the permissions of the mount command used. And permissions for user and group on the mountpoint and the contents of the disk. If any are NOT set to your user of group it will be read only.

Comment: I have tried it with `root` user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also face the same problem i try to change the mode of the media to access the file by the following command.

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/
```

Then try to access the Partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount your ntfs partition by command:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ntfs

sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw,permissions,users /dev/sdXX /mnt/ntfs
```

In `/etc/fstab` you could add it as:

```
/dev/sdXX /mnt/ntfs ntfs rw,users,permissions,auto 0 0
```

But better replace `/dev/sdXX` by UUID taken from `sudo blkid | grep sdXX` command:

```
UUID=96eaefa9-b32f-446b-baaf-c780f7fd8ada /mnt/ntfs ntfs rw,users,permissions,auto 0 0
```

Where `sdXX` is your ntfs partition you could get from `sudo fdisk -l | grep -v loop` command execution or in GParted.

If it mounts in read only mode, you should examine what is the issue. During mount command execution run `journalctl -f` on a separated console window to see what happens during it.

Also, you could change ownership of all your files and folders to be able to write to them:

```
sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /mnt/ntfs
```